# Determine if the differential equation will have an unique solution on D

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation $$y'=xe^{-y^{2}}$$
the boundary condition is $y(1)=e$ and $D=\{(x,y):x,y\in R, 1\le x \le 2\}$

I need to figure out if this has an unique solution on $D$

I have solved the differential equation as far as I could to be $$\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi}erfi(y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+c_1$$
Now from here I am unsure how to "solve for y" and how do I come to a conclusion if this has a unique solution or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the first and second derivatives of the function $g(y)=e^{-y^2}$:
$$
g'(y)= -2ye^{-y^2},\quad g''(y)=2(2y^2-1)e^{-y^2}
$$
We can see that $g'(y)$ has minimum and maximum values of 
$g'(\pm 1/\sqrt2)=\pm \sqrt{2/e}$, hence,
$$
|g'(y)|\le \sqrt{2/e}.
$$
It follows that (see, for example, Khalil, Nonlinear systems, Lemma 3.1)
$$
\forall y,z\in\mathbb R\quad |g(y)-g(z)|<\sqrt{\frac2{e}}\, |y-z|.
$$

Now we can use the following theorem (Khalil, Theorem 3.2):

$\bullet$ Suppose that $f(t,x)$ is piecewise continuous in $t$ and satisfies
$$
\forall x,y\in\mathbb R^n,\; \forall t\in [t_0,t_1]\quad \|f(t,x)-f(t,y)\|\le L\|x-y\|.
$$
Then, the state equation $\dot x=f(t,x)$ with $x(t_0)=x_0$ has an unique solution over $[t_0,t_1]$. $\bullet$

In our case $\forall y,z\in\mathbb R,\; \forall x\in [1,2]$
$$
\|f(x,y)-f(x,z)\|=\left|xe^{-y^2}-xe^{-z^2}\right|=|x|\cdot 
\left|g(y)-g(z)\right|<
2\sqrt{\frac2{e}}\, |y-z|,
$$
thus, the conditions of the theorem are satisfied.

Comment: That is a really cool trick, looking at $g'(y)$ and $g''(y)$.  ***Endorsed!***